# Convert String to Time Java.sql.time error

Tags: java, javafx

I want to convert a string to time using the parse method which is going to be inserted to database later. But I get: Incompatible Types: Java.util.date cannot be converted to Java.sql.Date. Any Solution?

```
String s = time.getText();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date d = sdf.parse(s);
```

Comment: Do you need a `java.sql.Time`? For your database? Which database? If you can use Java 8, you will probably want to check if your database can use a `java.time.LocalTime` instead, or one of the other classes in `java.time`. They are generally nicer to work with than the old classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: Yes I think I do. I'm using Mysql database and I can't get rid of the java.sql.Time because it doesn't accept any other type of object than time

Comment: I’m far away from my home field here, but the way I read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html, Connector/J version 5.1 supports JDBC version 4.2, which if my memory serves me right, should be enough that it can use the `java.time` classes. If this is correct, you can do without `java.sql.Time`. Haven’t been able to find it the docs, though.

Comment: Will try that but it's gonna make me change a lot of things in my project. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `parse()` method returns `java.util.Date` whereas you have imported `java.sql.Date`, so change the imported class to `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

the errors occurs when [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) imported which is derived from [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and [DateFormat.parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) return a `java.util.Date`. so you can't assign `java.util.Date` to derived type `java.sql.Date`.

```
import java.util.Date;
//not 
import java.sql.Date;
```

**OR** assign it to a full-name type of `java.util.Date` when you both using `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`:

```
java.util.Date d = sdf.parse(s);
```

**OR** if you need convert `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date` you can do as follows:

```
java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(s).getTime());
```

**OR** if you need convert `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Time` you can do as follows:

```
java.sql.Time d = new java.sql.Time(sdf.parse(s).getTime());
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it returns a Date object while I need to insert a Time object

Comment: @RymHaouachi what wrong?